# Leafletmap in cordova android app converted from vue is grey

Tags: javascript, android, vue.js, cordova

Im using :

[vue-cli-plugin-cordova](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-cli-plugin-cordova)

to convert a vue application with a leaflet map

After installing [vue-cli-plugin-cordova](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-cli-plugin-cordova) im running:

```
npm install -g cordova
vue add cordova
```

After that Im installing android studio, Java Development Kit (JDK) 8 and gradle

and are running the application using the eumulator in android studio the map returns blank
[image]

I cannot see any errormessage since I am running it through vs code.

Is it possible to view errormessages in android emulator? Like the console in a webbapplication?

Any hint of what could have gone wrong? Sorry not many leads since the lack of errormessages ...

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution in case anyone else have the same problem.

the url to my leaflet map was:

```
 url: "http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
```

changing http to https solved it:

```
 url: "https://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
```